# Why does caching a skewed dataset take more time in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I cache a skewed table in spark, it takes 4x times as compared to caching a uniformly distributed dataset. What I do is repartition the dataset uniformly before caching.
I want to know why this happens, isn't the dataset already in memory, how does caching take so much time?
I verified that even though the dataset was skewed, caching never overflowed to disk and was always accommodated in memory.

Sample Example

```
Dataset skewedDs = ds.read();
ds.cache();
ds.first();
```

Above takes 2.5mins to evaluate

```
Dataset skewedDs = ds.read();
    uniformDS = ds.repartition(n)
    uniformDS.cache();
    uniformDS.first();
```

Above takes 40secs to evaluate.
As you can see, simply caching a skewed dataset takes a huge chunk of time.

Comment: can you share the sample code you used to test? QQ - was the process flow something like this - skewed df creation -> repartition -> cache -> action - that took a lot of time? note - `df.cache()` simply marks the df for caching and it is actually cached in the next action executed on it (or using it)

Comment: were they executed in the same session or separate spark sessions? because `ds` was cached in the first test. BTW, first thoughts - I'm guessing spark had to read from a very large partition of the skewed data in the first test, and hence it took a lot of time. maybe try testing with `.count()` which will make spark read all partitions in both tests.

Comment: It's a skewed data set.  Why wouldn't it take longer?  All the skewed data needs to be evaluated, and the work is done by 1 executor.  And if it's badly skewed, it's also invalidating it's own cache as it goes...

What argument could be made it should take less time? ('m interested)

Comment: Why don't you check the computation dag to see which part takes time? I guess it should be related to the data reading and schema inference.

Comment: I have ensured that the read times are the same for both datasets.  I tried 2 scenarios. 
1) Read a dataset from the cache(previously stored), partition it in a skewed manner, and cache it.
2) Read a dataset from the cache(previously stored), partition it uniformly, and cache it.

Also noted, partitioning times for both cases were comparable. There seemed to be a massive difference in caching time.